# FFmpeg conversion to FLAC including Art

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, flac

I am using FFMpeg to convert audio formats and specifically to FLAC. I am unable to preserve album art in the metadata for some reason.

Current command format I am using is:

```
ffmpeg -I source.alac -c:v copy -f Flac destination.flac
```

Am I missing something, or does FFMpeg not actually support this? (I know I cane tract artwork and then use metallic if I need to but thats a lot more complex than I'd like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg does not support cover art in FLAC containers. There's an open ticket: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4442

There is a CLI tool, [metaflac](https://xiph.org/flac/documentation_tools_metaflac.html), which should be useful.